# React - What is the Best Way to use Multiple createContexts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've just learned about the createContext hook and I'm wondering what's the best approach to using multiple contexts globally throughout the project.

From what I've seen if you want to create and use multiple contexts it looks kinda messy having multiple nested Context tags and I'm wondering if there is a cleaner looking way of doing this?

(Example of how I think a project using four contexts would look)

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const OneContext = createContext();
export const TwoContext = createContext();
export const ThreeContext = createContext();
export const FourContext = createContext();

export default function App(){
    const [one, setOne] = useState(null);
    const [two, setTwo] = useState(null);
    const [three, setThree] = useState(null);
    const [four, setFour] = useState(null);

   return(
        <>
            <OneContext.Provider value={one}>
                <TwoContext.Provider value={two}>
                    <ThreeContext.Provider value={three}>
                        <FourContext.Provider value={four}>            
                            "Insert components here"
                        <FourContext.Provider />
                    <ThreeContext.Provider />
                <TwoContext.Provider />
            <OneContext.Provider />
        </>
   )
}
```

Comment: It's unclear why you would need multiple contexts in your example. Could you manage state with `useReducer` instead?

Comment: What I'm wanting to do is have multiple variables which can be accessed by all child components.

Comment: Aside from the fact that you may not actually need multiple contexts as ksav pointed out, is what you have really all that "ugly"?

Comment: It is subjectively ugly to me.

Comment: You can always hide it in a component: `const ProvidesAllTheThings = ({ children }) => (<OneContext.Provider value={one}>....{children})` rather than have your App code indented 24 spaces.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know it was possible to access the children like that. Thank you for letting me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that

```
<AppContext.Provider
  value={{
    oneCTX: [one, setOne],
    twoCTX: [two, setTwo],
    threeCTX: [three,setThree]
  }}
>
  {props.children}
</AppContext.Provider>
```

on the other files, you can call them like this, Import AppContext from the context.js file first, then do that

```
const { oneCTX } = useContext(AppContext);
const [one, setOne] = loggedUserCTX;
```

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I was looking for. I forgot I could simply create a dictionary as the value.

Comment: Notice that all context consumers will re-render when the context provider updates the value, no matter what part of the value each consumer is actually using.

Comment: I'll take that into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

> [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) is usually preferable to useState when you have complex state logic that involves multiple sub-values or when the next state depends on the previous one.

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from "react";

const OneContext = createContext();

const initialState = {one:null, two:null, three:null, four:null};

function reducer(state, action) {
  return {
    ...state,
    [action.type]: action.payload
  }
}

export default function App(){
   const stateAndDispatch = useReducer(reducer, initialState)
   return(
        <>
            <OneContext.Provider value={stateAndDispatch}>       
                "Insert components here"
            <OneContext.Provider />
        </>
   )
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate further on how useReducer would help my situation? What I'm trying to achieve Is an easy way to send the value to all the components without needing to send it as a prop.  e.g. sending a theme (light or dark) and each component changing its CSS accordingly.

Comment: Your stated problem was `it looks kinda messy having multiple nested Context tags and I'm wondering if there is a cleaner looking way of doing this`. So `useReducer` eliminates those nested providers by combining all the state to a single reducer.

Comment: After looking into useReducer, I think the other answer provided a more suitable solution for what it is I'm trying to do. Thank you for the suggestion though.